# Nuxt.js Deployment to Ubuntu 18.04 with Plesk Obsidian - How is this working?

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, ubuntu-18.04, plesk

I've build my first Nuxt.js app and want to deploy it to my Webserver. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Plesk Obsidian as VPS from Strato. After developing a few larger Vuejs Applications I've created a Nuxt.js app including SSR.

I hope somebody can tell me, how this is working with Nuxt.

Thanks.